# Connotation of "Fool" is perhaps that it is by choice?

Tags: meaning

There are words that imply that the person is unintelligent because of genetics or accident but I am looking for a word that describes a person who behaves in an unintelligent fashion because of pride or because they believe they are more competent than they actually are.

But if such a person sat down and evaluated things, they would realize, for example, that maybe they don't have what it takes to get a doctorate and so they would go into a profession for which they are better suited, and therefore, would no longer be a fool.

I realize that the word at one time did simply mean "an unintelligent person" but am I right about "fool" being a good word to describe a person who deludes himself about his own ability and so seems dumb? And if "fool" is not the right word, what is?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114041/discussion-on-question-by-releseabe-connotation-of-fool-is-perhaps-that-it-is).

Answer (score 0):

You ask for “a word that describes a person who behaves in an unintelligent fashion because of pride or because they believe they are more competent than they actually are.” My only offering is the hyphenated “self-deluded”, which is almost always applied to those whose whose opinion of themselves exceeds their abilities rather than to those whose opinion is less than their abilities.

You also ask if “fool” is appropriate to such a person. In some circumstances, “self-deluded fool” may be appropriate for a self-deluded person, particularly one who does foolish (=unwise and imprudent, rather than mere jesting or comic) things as a result of their belief.

Answer (score -1):

No, you are not right in saying that a fool is a person who deludes themselves about their own abilities and so seems dumb, or rather you are only partially right as this describes just a particular type of fool. A more general definition is needed. OALD provides that definition: "*A person who **behaves** or **speaks** in a way that lacks **intelligence** or **good manners*** SYNONYM idiot.

I think there is no single word term fitting your description; you have to rely upon phrases, for instances phrases using "out of".

- a fool out of pride, a fool out of short-sightedness